# Find Smallest of Two numbers using Java -

Tags: java

So I have an assignment where I need to find the smallest of two numbers entered using java. Here are the instructions:

Input a set of positive integers, ending with -1 as a sentinel. Print the smallest and second smallest of these numbers in that order. These two numbers may be equal to each other – see the second example below.

You should check that there are at least two numbers input before the -1, so that there always will be a smallest and second smallest number. (Hint: you may want to input the first two numbers separately, before you start a loop that inputs the rest of the numbers.) If the first or second number is -1, you should call IO.reportBadInput and halt the program.

Examples:

java TwoSmall
32
11
19
7
-1
RESULT: 7
RESULT: 11

I have done the assignment but I was wondering if there is a simpler way of doing this:

Here is my code:

```
public class TwoSmall
{
public static void main(String[]args){
int smallest,secondSmallest,temp = 0;


System.out.println("Please enter a number");
smallest = IO.readInt();
System.out.println("Please enter a number");
secondSmallest = IO.readInt();

    // Used to sort intial two numbers
    if (smallest>secondSmallest){

        temp = smallest;
        smallest = secondSmallest;
        secondSmallest = temp;

    }

    if (smallest !=-1 && secondSmallest !=-1){
        while (temp != -1){
            System.out.println("Please enter a number");
            temp = IO.readInt();
                if (temp<smallest && temp != -1){
                    secondSmallest = smallest;
                    smallest = temp;
                }else if (temp<secondSmallest && temp != -1){
                    secondSmallest = temp;
                }

        }
        IO.outputIntAnswer(smallest);
        IO.outputIntAnswer(secondSmallest);
    }else {
        IO.reportBadInput();
    }       
}
}
```

I feel like I have written too much code for a simple problem.

Comment: Do you need the smallest of two numbers, or the smallest 2 numbers in a set? These are two very different problems :)

Comment: This is a homework problem so I don't want to give too much away, but can't you just say `compare(a,b);` and then in your compare function `if a<b return a` `if b<a return b`

Comment: Your question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java

Comment: This should go here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hint how to make code compact: use sorting

Comment: I agree with a CodeReview transfer. I would like to note that many students come here for answers to a problem, only few of them provide their work in progress. Thanks for the honesty and for not taking us for slaves!

Comment: Smallest *of* two numbers: `Math.min(a, b)`.

Comment: @BarneyChambers at the end of the program the output should give the two smallest numbers that were entered. the program must be done using some sort of loop. in my class we haven't gotten to the part where we can use the compare function so I am assuming the teacher wants us to use a loop.

Comment: @SteeveDroz No problem! I have no intention of making people do my work. I want to learn this as much as I can but a little help along the way would be nice just to learn some tips. My program works but i just wanted to see if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

As you have stated in the question this is a homework assignment so people will be reluctant to give you the answer. Your question is a little confusing whether you want to find the smallest 2 numbers in a set **or** if you want to compare two numbers and return the smallest one. Here is a high level approach to each

**Find 2 smallest numbers in set**

- Put all numbers in array.
- Sort array.
- return `array[0]` and `array[1]`

**Compare two numbers and return smallest**

- Declare function that takes in two arguments `a` and `b`
- `if (a<b) return a;`
- `if (b<a) return b;`
- `else` they are the same!

Comment: Sorting would be an overhead in first problem of `finding 2 smallest numbers` in a set.OP has better approach for that problem as given in the code which works in `O(n)`.

Comment: You're right. The steps I have provided is a very simple approach to the problem that is easy to understand

Comment: @Barney Chambers - I havent gotten to arrays yet in my class. My main concern was that in my while loop i put that smallest != -1 and secondSmallest != -1, and then i have to again state in my if else statement that smallest and secondSmallest != -1. I was wondering if there was  away to make this more compact so I would only have to state the != once.

Answer (score 0):

for whatever is worth, this gives you the smaller of any amount of numbers while ignoring nulls (just make sure your list is made of the same type of numbers, Integer, Long, Float, etc)

smaller = Arrays.asList(3,6).stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).sorted().findFirst().orElse(null);